# Error converting pandas dataframe to ORC using pyarrow

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyarrow, orc

I'm trying to save a Pandas DataFrame as .orc file using Pyarrow. The versions of packages are: `pandas==1.3.5` and `pyarrow==6.0.1`. My python3 version is `3.9.12`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.orc as orc

df = pd.read_orc('sample.orc')
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
orc.write_table(table, 'sample_rewritten.orc')
```

The error I'm getting is: `ArrowNotImplementedError: Unknown or unsupported Arrow type: null`

How do I save a Pandas DataFrame (csv) as .orc file in python?

The `write_table` line is failing.
This is the entire stack trace:

```
ArrowNotImplementedError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 7>()
      5 df = pd.read_orc('hats_v2_sample.orc')
      6 table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
----> 7 orc.write_table(table, 'sample_rewritten.orc')

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/orc.py:176, in write_table(table, where)
    174     table, where = where, table
    175 writer = ORCWriter(where)
--> 176 writer.write(table)
    177 writer.close()

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/orc.py:146, in ORCWriter.write(self, table)
    136 def write(self, table):
    137     """
    138     Write the table into an ORC file. The schema of the table must
    139     be equal to the schema used when opening the ORC file.
   (...)
    144         The table to be written into the ORC file
    145     """
--> 146     self.writer.write(table)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/_orc.pyx:159, in pyarrow._orc.ORCWriter.write()

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi:120, in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowNotImplementedError: Unknown or unsupported Arrow type: null
```

Comment: which line is failing exactly? `from_pandas` or `write_table`? Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: I have updated the question with entire stack trace

Comment: It looks like your source table has got a column of type `pa.null()` (which means it doesn't have any data).

It also looks like orc doesn't support null columns. You need to figure out which column(s) is causing the issue, and why. To do so you can call `print(table.schema)` which will tell you the type of each column.

Comment: Right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if you're able to wait, but Pandas v1.5.0 natively supports writing to ORC files.

```
DataFrame.to_orc()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#writing-to-orc-files
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44554

Comment: Thanks for the information. Does this allow converting pandas DataFrames with empty columns to orc file?

Comment: @Heyb - it's released now. You'd have to try it out

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises when you are exporting data with null values in data frame.
You can use df.fillna(value = 0,inplace = True)
And then export the data frame to orc file